# How does Folder Watcher work in JDK 7?

Tags: java, operating-system, directory, subdirectory, java-7

I'm developing a Java application and I need to see if in a folder appears new files or new folders. My problem is that Folder Watcher only listens for modifications in the first level in the folder tree and I need to see if new folders are created in all my subfolders of the tree structure. My idea is put folder watchers on all my subfolders. I don't know how efficient this is because I don't know what causes the event that a file is created|deleted|modified. My hope is that the OS signals an event that a new file has been created in the File System and this somehow makes some calls on JVM. Is my guess correct? because I need an efficient way to know that a file has been created in my folder structure.

Answer (score 3):

The [JavaDoc of `WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) says this:

> The implementation that observes events from the file system is intended to map directly on to the native file event notification facility where available, or to use a primitive mechanism, such as polling, when a native facility is not available.

In other words: if the OS provides an efficient way to implement this, then that way should be used by the VM, if the OS doesn't provide such a way, then a simpler (but more expensive) polling mechanism is used.

That being said, most modern operating systems *do* have the necessary file-watching APIs, but their specific implementation differs. Some allow watching whole sub-trees, while others watch only one level deep (like the Java API does). That's probably also the reason why the `WatcherService` only watches one level deep by default.

Comment: So, would it be optimal to use the WatcherService on all my sub-folders or there is a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: As a rule, `WatcherService` does the smartest thing it can think of.  It's probably not worth trying to reinvent a smarter implementation.